# How to go about jobhunting when you only want a job so that you can get enough money to move away?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, new-job, job-change

I'm a semi-recent college grad (~9 months out of college). I want to move from my minor city to New York City but I want to save 4 to 5k before I do that. Therefore, I have to get a job but I'll probably be able to save 5k in six months.

How do I handle this? Should I job search like normal? Look for six month positions? Should I stay a year just to try to be nice to whichever company hires me?

To add to the complications, I recently left my old job for Colombia thinking English teaching was what I wanted to do, then came back realizing I couldn't really hack it in Colombia.

Luckily I've been getting interview offers left and right but I'm not sure what to say in them, especially when they ask me why I want to work.

I'm an English major with a series 6 and 63 license and 7 months insurance sales experience if that matters at all.

Comment: Why not casual jobs? Some pay very well.

Comment: Are you living at home?  What bills do you pay?  There's a lot of information that is left out here.  I can save 5k easily in 2-3 months because I live at home and don't pay for bills.

Comment: They ask you why you want to work???

Comment: We can't really tell you how to perform your job search, since this will heavily depend on how easily you can find a job and how much you care about potentially burning bridges, but we can tell you how to answer ["why do you want to join our company"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12659) or ["how long will you stay with us"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/81836), [whether to mention moving plans](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/104772) or [how to resign from a new job](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7149).

Comment: Why do you want the savings before moving? What's the difference between having no savings now in your current location and no savings now in New York? Is it the cost of moving?

Answer (score 4):

You need to balance what's good for you with your conscience. You decide how much conscience you have :-)

My personal recommendation: Apply and find a job. Don't tell them you want to leave soon to move somewhere else, because nobody will hire you. Do your best to do a good job, save as much money as you can, and move away when you can say with good conscience that the company got what it paid for (which is obviously not the case after two or three months). If you say you can save $5,000 in three months, then you can save some significant amount in one year, which will give you a much much better start elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at this from a different perspective.

What would you do if I just gave you $5k to keep and make a fresh start in NYC? Would you do it? Chances are you would - what you really seem to want to do here is to make your *real* start in New York City rather than the city you're currently in(let's call it X). But, the problem there is that the costs of living in NYC are so damn high that no one with zero money will be able to make it there for enough time to find a job.

Make it about *them* and not about *you*.

Companies won't care about where you want to start your career, they only want to know why you're applying at their company. When they realize that you'd leave the moment you have enough money to move to another city/company, then it'll be almost a no-brainer to not hire you.

I'd say you should evaluate what you want to be doing when you do start a job in NYC, and then look for a similar position in the current city. Then you'll be able to both save money and apply for a better job in NYC when you have adequate experience in what you want to do.

Win/win both ways.